# best empirical macro/micro F1 score?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, python, multilabel

In the following [presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nNDqbUhtIRg#t=1835) it's said that "0.5 to 0.55 (micro) F1 score is best for multilabel classification problems"

I tried to investigate this statement but couldn't find the source.

Does anyone know if there is more to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're missing the context here: He says that results reported in the literature *on this task* (multi-label document categorization) are typically around 0.5-0.55, but the Kaggle leaderboard had some people reporting results that were much higher (~0.8).  He then discusses why (the test set contained copies of training examples) and how he built a system that used that information, plus other data, which performed really well.

He doesn't mention where he got that "typical" range from, but it's not totally unreasonable. This paper by [T .Rubin et al.](http://psiexp.ss.uci.edu/research/papers/RubinEtAl_2011_MLJ_SpecialIssue_2ndResubmission_V14p1.pdf) reports pretty similar F1 values in Table 8, but the numbers in this [comparison of two systems](https://web.cs.dal.ca/~luo/ISMIS05-xn.pdf) are a bit higher.

There's nothing magical about 0.5. Depending on the task, a number much less than 0.5 might be a cause for celebration or even something like 0.95 might be disappointing.

Answer (score 1):

On an extremely easy data set, anything but a F1 of 1.0 is a failure. ;-)

On a data set, where $l$ labels are assigned at random with the same probability, precision and recall of much more than $1/l$ are either due to chance or due to cheating.

Real data will of course be somewhere inbetween.

Now here is the catch: if you have a *balanced, binary* classification problem, and answer at random. You have a chance of 50% to get the values right, so **on a balanced, binary classiciation problem, F1 of 0.5 is the expected performance of a *random* classifier**. So any result around 0.5 is useless. This does, however, not generalize to balanced multiclass problems!

So maybe that was the statement where that number came from: 0.5 on a binary problem is random; but 0.5 on a 100-class problem *can* be pretty good (if it is a balanced, difficult data set without issues such as duplicates etc.). The statement probably never was 0.5 is "best".

So since a random result is expected to achieve $1/l$ as F1-measure, you could define an adjusted F1 measure that is less sensitive to the class size:

$$adjF1_l:=\frac{F1 - 1/l}{1 - 1/l}$$

But this equation assumes that all classes are equally frequent, so it is not a general purpose thing.

Comment: I refer to your last paragraph: by now I also think that this person wasn't referring to a special book/paper/survey etc. and just wanted to express, that the 0.5-55 range is "fine" for these kind of problems. His slides can be easily misunderstood, because the phrase "is tops" [is this even grammatically correct?]  implies that there is some kind of cap. His statement "literature says if you do best practices you should be able to get 0.5 - 0.55"  doesn't imply that this is the best possible value. I think it boils down to what I said in the beginning